# Why is $0 \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X/A) \to 0$ exact?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a subspace of $X$. Is

$$0 \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X/A) \to 0$$

exact at the middle homology group? Here $i_*: H_n(A) \to H_n(X)$ is the map induced by the inclusion $i: A \to X$ and $q_*:H_n(X) \to H_n(X/A)$ is the map induced by the quotient map $q: X \to X/A$.

I was able to show that $\operatorname{Im}(i_*) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(q_*)$ but I wonder if the other inclusion also holds?

If not, can we say more if $A$ is a deformation retract of an open subset of $X$?

Comment: Yes, but how does that help? I'm specifically asking if it is true that $\operatorname{Im}(i_*) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(q_*)$ (if $A$ is a deformation retract of an open subset of $X$). I'm aware of the result you quote, but the isomorphism $H_n(X,A) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ seems non-canonical so I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: Here is an example of this sequence not being exact if $A \to X$ is not a cofibration: consider $X = S^n$ and $A = S^n \setminus p$ (where $p$ is any point), then in fact $X/A$ is a contractible $2$-point set so in degree $n$ we would have $0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to 0$, which cannot be exact.

Comment: Hatcher proves that $H_n(X, A) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ under the assumption that $(X, A)$ is a "good pair", or specifically if $A$ is a deformation retract of an open subset of $X$. I believe in this case you can follow @NoelLundström's suggestion to prove exactness.

Comment: Writing $0 \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X/A) \to 0$ is misleading because it suggests that it might be a short exact sequence. This is certainly not true. I suggest you write $ H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X/A)$. There is no use to add $0$ at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @NoelLundström You should give an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true but only if $i$ is a cofibration. Use the long exact sequence for the pair $(X,A)$ and the identity $H_n(X,A)=H^r_n(X/A)$ where the $r$ stands for reduced homology.

Beware though, that identity generally only holds if $i$ is a cofibration.

Comment: It might be better to say that this is true **if** $i$ is a cofibration.